# WebPack is trying to load all required modules and then breaking

Tags: node.js, webpack, require, webpack-2

I'm using webpack to build a project where the client and server-side share certain concepts (a shared state). Because of this, I've set up webpack to compile *both* of them, like so:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = [
  {
    entry: './lib/client.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static')
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['babel-preset-env', 'babel-preset-react']
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    entry: './lib/server.js',
    target: 'node',
    output: {
      filename: 'index.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname)
    }
  }
]
```

Unfortunately, when this compiles, webpack seems to be loading up every `require`'d module on the server-side and breaking when it can't find them. It's even trying to load some `.node` modules, which cause it to output a warning.

It finally breaks at this error, probably a result of my server code having `require('pg')` in it:

```
 ERROR in ./node_modules/pg/lib/native/client.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pg-native' in 'C:\...\node_modules\pg\lib\native'
     @ ./node_modules/pg/lib/native/client.js 10:13-33
     @ ./node_modules/pg/lib/native/index.js
     @ ./node_modules/pg/lib/index.js
     @ ./lib/server.js
```

How do I get it to ignore the required modules and just keep them as regular `require` calls in the output? `target: 'node'` doesn't seem to help.

**Update:** For whatever reason, trying to build the exact same project on my Linux system works perfectly, so it seems to be a platform-specific problem.

Answer (score -2):

> I think you are using or importing 'pg-native' module in one of the Javascript file.
>
> If you want it to work then install that module **npm install pg-native --save**
> If you don't want to use 'pg-native' then better you refactor your code and remove usage of it

Comment: That is wrong. The error is saying the thing that could not be resolved is in `node_modules`, so `npm install ...` will not solve the problem. Yes, it will solve the `pg-native` problem, but another dependency will popout with the same error.

Comment: it shouldn't be requiring pg-native in the first place, because that package is an optional dependency. The only reason it's trying to find it is because webpack is finding every single `require` call in every file and trying to operate upon the required file, which it shouldn't be doing because nodejs is responsible for loading these files at runtime. Not to mention, I can't install pg-native right now because of problems compiling the native module - though I shouldn't need it at all.